# Integratiing Bonita and Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bonita

I am trying to integrate Bonita with Spring in order to implement a custom UI for my workflow processes. I know Bonita provides a REST API out-of-the-box for this matter but I was thinking maybe there is already a java library for this API ready to use with Spring.

I started implementing RESTTemplate consumers for this API but it is quite heavy so I might take advantage of a working solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using REST API you might want to access Bonita Engine API using the [Java client library](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/product-bos-sp/engine-api).

You can find available APIs in the [javadoc](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/javadoc/api/7.0/com/bonitasoft/engine/api/package-summary.html).